# How to create a function that takes N numbers and produces a list of lists with those element numbers, as in the example?

Tags: functional-programming

Someone knows how to make a function **create n)** that takes **N** numbers, and produces a list of lists with those element numbers. The elements of each list must be integers in ascending order

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Renzo Here's how I tried and thought, I edited the post

Comment: Why did you remove all that information from your post? Now it is very difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably expected to write it in a functional way, in particular without side-effects. It is possible and without revealing too much, I suggest writing 3 functions:

- `range-list` of two parameters `from` and `to`, which builds a list of numbers with both inclusive bounds; for example `(range-list 2 4)` is `(2 3 4)`
- `make-lists` which takes a `start` parameter (the next integer from which generating integers), and a `sizes` parameter (a list), a list of sizes. It calls `range-list` to build lists and recurses to itself to build the next list of lists.
- the `answer` function (you can rename it), which takes a variable amount of parameters, and calls `make-lists` with a start of 1 and the given list of sizes.

I implemented this in Common Lisp and traced all those functions with your example, the output is as follows (nb. don't mind the `SO::` prefix, it is the current package (a namespace), it stands for *StackOverflow*):

```
  0: (SO::ANSWER 4 3 3)
    1: (SO::MAKE-LISTS 1 (4 3 3))
      2: (SO::RANGE-LIST 1 4)
        3: (SO::RANGE-LIST 2 4)
          4: (SO::RANGE-LIST 3 4)
            5: (SO::RANGE-LIST 4 4)
              6: (SO::RANGE-LIST 5 4)
              6: RANGE-LIST returned NIL
            5: RANGE-LIST returned (4)
          4: RANGE-LIST returned (3 4)
        3: RANGE-LIST returned (2 3 4)
      2: RANGE-LIST returned (1 2 3 4)
      2: (SO::MAKE-LISTS 5 (3 3))
        3: (SO::RANGE-LIST 5 7)
          4: (SO::RANGE-LIST 6 7)
            5: (SO::RANGE-LIST 7 7)
              6: (SO::RANGE-LIST 8 7)
              6: RANGE-LIST returned NIL
            5: RANGE-LIST returned (7)
          4: RANGE-LIST returned (6 7)
        3: RANGE-LIST returned (5 6 7)
        3: (SO::MAKE-LISTS 8 (3))
          4: (SO::RANGE-LIST 8 10)
            5: (SO::RANGE-LIST 9 10)
              6: (SO::RANGE-LIST 10 10)
                7: (SO::RANGE-LIST 11 10)
                7: RANGE-LIST returned NIL
              6: RANGE-LIST returned (10)
            5: RANGE-LIST returned (9 10)
          4: RANGE-LIST returned (8 9 10)
          4: (SO::MAKE-LISTS 11 NIL)
          4: MAKE-LISTS returned NIL
        3: MAKE-LISTS returned ((8 9 10))
      2: MAKE-LISTS returned ((5 6 7) (8 9 10))
    1: MAKE-LISTS returned ((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7) (8 9 10))
  0: ANSWER returned ((1 2 3 4) (5 6 7) (8 9 10))
```

This should help you get started.

In this implementations those were non-terminal recursive functions. Note however how `range-list` could push items starting from the `end`. Also, if you preprocess the `sizes` list in a terminal recursive way (like a fold/reduce), you can determine which is the last integer, and build the lists from the last to the first, again in a terminal recursive way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple minded solution.

First, I build a sequence, then partition according to the arguments:

```
#lang racket

(define (create-lln f . r)
  ; collects all args into a list
  (define l (cons f r))
  ; builds sequence from [1, (sum l)]
  (define seq (build-list (apply + l) add1))
  ; partitioning
  (take-multiple l seq))

; partitions `taken-list` by `taking-list`
; example:
; (take-multiple '(3 4 4) '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11))
; => '((1 2 3) (4 5 6 7) (8 9 10 11))
(define (take-multiple taking-list taken-list)
  (cond [(empty? taking-list) empty]
        [else (begin
                (define f (first taking-list))
                (cons
                 (take taken-list f)
                 (take-multiple (rest taking-list) (list-tail taken-list f))))]))
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know how to do it in Racket, but my logic would be something like:

```
ListOfLists = new List()
indexEntry = 0
j = 1
listTemp = new List()
while (indexInput <ListOfLists.size()){
     while(TempList.size() < Entry[Input index]){
         listTemp.Add(j)
         j = j+1
     }
     ListOfLists.Add(TempList)
     listTemp = new List()
     indexInput = indexInput +1
}
```